# Symfony: Custom ExceptionController

Tags: symfony, exception

Am working on a symfony2.8 application, and i'am trying to override the showAction of the exceptionController, everything works fine except i can't get the current loggedin user, the security.token_storage always returns null.
security.yaml :

```
security:
    encoders:
       FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt
role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN
providers:
    fos_userbundle:
         id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login: 
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_provider: security.csrf.token_manager
            check_path: fos_user_security_check
            login_path: fos_user_security_login
            default_target_path: default_security_target
            use_referer: true
        logout:
            path: fos_user_security_logout
            target: default_security_target         
        anonymous: true  
        remember_me:
            key: "%secret%"
            lifetime: 604800 
            path: /
access_control:
    - { path: ^/login, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

and in the config i declare the controller as service under the services block:                                         `twig.controller.exception:
        class: %twig.controller.exception.class%
        arguments: ["@twig",%kernel.debug%,"@security.token_storage"]`
and here is my controller:

```
namespace test\testBundle\Controller;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\TemplateReference;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\FlattenException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Log\DebugLoggerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\Controller\ExceptionController as baseController;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface;

 class ExceptionController extends baseController
 {
   private $tokenStorage;

public function __construct(\Twig_Environment $twig,$debug,TokenStorage $tokenStorage)
{
    parent::__construct($twig,$debug);
    $this->tokenStorage= $tokenStorage;
}
/**
 * Converts an Exception to a Response.
 *
 * @param Request              $request   The request
 * @param FlattenException     $exception A FlattenException instance
 * @param DebugLoggerInterface $logger    A DebugLoggerInterface instance
 * @param string               $_format   The format to use for rendering (html, xml, ...)
 *
 * @return Response
 *
 * @throws \InvalidArgumentException When the exception template does not exist
 */
public function showAction(Request $request, FlattenException $exception, DebugLoggerInterface $logger = null, $_format = 'html')
{
    /*** $this->securityContext is a pitfall never use it here recommended by the documentation
        $user = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();//$this->tokenStorage->getToken() is always null

    if (!is_object($user) || !$user instanceof UserInterface) {
        $user=null;
    }

    $currentContent = $this->getAndCleanOutputBuffering($request->headers->get('X-Php-Ob-Level', -1));
    $code = $exception->getStatusCode();
        return new Response($this->twig->render(
            $this->findTemplate($request, $_format, $code, $this->debug),
            array(
                'status_code'    => $code,
                'status_text'    => isset(Response::$statusTexts[$code]) ? Response::$statusTexts[$code] : '',
                'exception'      => $exception,
                'logger'         => $logger,
                'currentContent' => $currentContent
            )
        ));
}
}
```

any suggestions,please!

Comment: Add the related code.

Comment: inside the showAction i call $this->tokenStorage->getToken(); it returns null , giving that tokenstorage is injetced service inside the controller which is service itself

Comment: @ZeSoft: No, what he meant was update your question with the actual code. Also, please include your `security.xml` - that one should give us a hint why this does not work

Comment: this happens just with the exceptioncontroller but other controllers it's fine i can get the connected user

Comment: It's always better to see your code to clearly understand what you need or what are you trying to achieve (sorry if I was a bit sintetic :-)). I think Jovan pointed you in the right direction. PS: Symfony have many built-in events to hook in different points of it's Request/Response workflow that allow you to modify any behavior and adapt it to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

I compared the original `ExceptionController` class with yours and there are minor differences, all around the `tokenStorage`. As such, I don't see much point of hacking into the `TwigBundle` just to intercept an exception and provide the `Response`.

For that purpose, there is an event call `KERNEL_EXCEPTION` to which to can listen and, if needed, swap the `Response` with your own. The page [Events and Event Listeners](http://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html) describes how.

So, basically:

1. Create your own service and inject TokenStorage
2. Tag it with `kernel.exception`
3. In your service, decide what you want to do and put, if needed:

   ```
   $event->setResponse($myNewResponse);
   ```

That should do the trick. Hope this helps...

Comment: tokenstorage is injected because there is a code i didn't past which use the informations of the connected user. and i have already used the onkernelException but also the user is null even when i set priority to 255 so the code will be executed after the setting of the token storage, but nothing seem to work